# Build a web application on top of neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

I've been so far developing my web site using php on top of MySQL. What would be the recommended CMS to quickly develop web sites on top of neo4j ? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no CMS's per se (except maybe Structr depending on your needs).

In PHP, you can pick a framework of your choice (like Laravel or Symfony) and use the GraphAware Neo4j-OGM (https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-ogm ) for PHP, which has the same idea than Doctrine2 on top of mysql.

You can see an example with laravel here :

You just write your models :

https://github.com/ikwattro/laravel-neo4j-php-ogm-demo/tree/master/app/Model

And for querying you use the model repositories:

https://github.com/ikwattro/laravel-neo4j-php-ogm-demo/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/WelcomeController.php#L35

Comment: The idea is to replace the MySQL db and improve the look and feel of our web site squash-verrieres.fr with a minimum work, ease maintaining and include all functionalities of the current site.

Comment: Right then you can use the neo4j ogm as standalone library and plug it with your app, concerning look and feel you might consider bootstrap.

Comment: This is indeed an option, but with a lot of work. I had in mind to do the other way round, replace most of the site with a CMS and only code what is specific to our site per se reservation and wanted to take this opportunity to replace the mysql db with neo4j which offers me to handle relationships between players and opponent recommendation. I'll take a look at your ogm. Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid replacing a cms persistence layer is more work that you think, Drupal, joomla, wordpress and like have their own abstraction which will already take time to understand

Comment: Indeed, for this reason I didn't select any of these.